# Change the input value inside tag on click Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have got a list of preset questions in a collapsible, when i click on the edit icon I get a modal in which there's a form to change the text of this preset question.

I want to have only one modal and change the  shown when you click on it to the pre-set question. I've managed to change the second question's input value on click which is great, but i cannot get the other ones to stay as they were.

see the code below:

```
<li class="active" id="one">
    <div class="collapsible-header">
     <span>Question 1</span>        
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <span id="questionOne">What is your given name?</span>
      <a href="#editModal" data-target="editModal" class="modal-trigger"><i class="material-icons right" id="edit1">edit</i></a>    
    </div>
</li>
<li class="">
  <div class="collapsible-header">
    <span id="questionTwo">Question 2</span>        
  </div>
  <div class="collapsible-body">
    <span>What is your surname?</span>
    <a href="#editModal" data-target="editModal" class="modal-trigger"><i class="material-icons right" id="edit2">edit</i></a>    
  </div>
</li>
```

this is the modal:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
  <input value="What's your given name?" id="given_name" type="text" class="">
  <label class="active" for="given_name">Question:</label>
</div>
```

and this is the Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#edit2").click(function(){
            $("#given_name").val("What is your surname?");
        })
    })
```

I guess it has something to do with changing what is inside the val, but what?

Comment: Don't use the value for prompts like this, use a placeholder.

Comment: What do you mean by "the other ones"? There's just one modal.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to attack it. You can have an object with the text and update it.

```js
const fields = {
  one: {
    label: 'First',
    placeholder: 'First Placeholder',
  },
  two: {
    label: 'Second',
    placeholder: 'Second Placeholder',
  },
}

$("a[data-edit]").on("click", function () {
  const info = fields[this.dataset.edit];
  $('label[for="modalInput1"]').text(info.label);
  $('#modalInput1').attr('placeholder', info.placeholder).val('');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<a href="#" class="" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-edit="one">
  Edit 1
</a>

<a href="#" class="" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-edit="two">
  Edit 2
</a>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="modalInput1" class="form-label"></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalInput1" placeholder="">
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```